# libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, shared-libraries, redhat

I am trying to run a script (ruby script) on a linux server. I get the below error:
I am not sure what the issue is but it looks a like shared library issue. Linux experts, can you please enlighten what the issue might be?

```
libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:9:in `postgresql_connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `checkout_new_connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `loop'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `block in checkout'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `checkout'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:94:in `connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.2/lib/arel/table.rb:127:in `table_cache'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.2/lib/arel/table.rb:122:in `tables'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.2/lib/arel/table.rb:118:in `table_exists?'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.2/lib/arel/table.rb:97:in `[]'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:23:in `block in build_from_hash'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:9:in `each'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:9:in `map'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:9:in `build_from_hash'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:227:in `build_where'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:77:in `where'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:221:in `destroy_all'
/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:439:in `destroy_all'
./edx_vert_to_pg.rb:43:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I dont know what the steps are to troubleshoot something like this. What is the issue first of all? Can you explain? thank you

Comment: Sorry not too familiar with .so or C or anything like that. But I found the libpq.so.5 in the directory `/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib` and when I did an `ls -l` on it, i see there is a link.. `libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.4`... Is this a red flag?

Comment: The permissions are fine. I am able to read it. Here is the ls -l output: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Sep 12  2012 libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.4`

Comment: I am having this same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

libpq.so.5 is unable to read this file

/gds/apps/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so

does the file exist ?
does the file have correct permissions to be read by the program you're executing and failing ?

that should get you going